# Unable to initialize the video obtain properties (videoreader in Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I can read one video using Matlab in windows but cannot read the same video from Matlab in ubuntu 14.04.  The error is as follows:

```
>> aa = VideoReader('s12_32_xvid.avi');
Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
Could not read file due to an unexpected error. Reason: Unable to initialize the video obtain properties

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Is the required codec present on your system?

Comment: This might be a missing codec issue. Can you copy this file to a /tmp and execute the following command on the Linux terminal window?
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file:///tmp/s12_32_xvid.avi 

If this works, it should bring up a window displaying the movie? If the command results in an error, you need to install codecs. try the gstreamer ffmpeg package.

Comment: Checkout vatsal's answer below

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me. You need to install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg.

https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/255157-can-t-load-video-using-videoreader-in-matlab-r2015-on-ubuntu-15-04-could-not-read-file-due-to-an-un

The instructions to install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg are here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/575869/how-do-i-install-gstreamer0-10-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-10

Hope it helped

Comment: Thanks. The combination solved for me ubuntu 16.04 + Matlab 2016b

Answer (score 0):

After installing the gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg, the problem may still exists, due to a missing codec. You may install the codecs using:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```