# MATLAB: Unable to initialize the video obtain properties

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-16.04

I want to use VideoReader() in MATLAB 2017b on Ubuntu 16.04. While trying to use this function I get to this error:

```
>> obj= VideoReader('video.mp4');
Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
Could not read file due to an unexpected error. Reason: Unable to initialize the video obtain properties

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to initialize the video obtain properties (videoreader in Matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486233/unable-to-initialize-the-video-obtain-properties-videoreader-in-matlab)

Comment: Are you **sure** you tried that link?  Please tell us how you installed GStreamer and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thanks my friends for your comments and trying to help. Yes, I read the link you mentioned. The problem was that the needed codecs were not installed. After I tried to open the video with the player it suggested me to install some packages:
`gstreamer1.0-libav`
`gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad`
`gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers`

Finally, I prepared my solution as described below in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the problem described above. It took me several hours to solve. I found many people face the same problem. So, I decided to describe my solution here, so that others can use it.

To solve this problem you need to have ffmpeg and gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg. You need to add PPA and then install the packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-tools 
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

**Note:** VideoReader support **GStreamer 0.10**.

You may still need some other plugins. I suggest you to **play the video** so that more needed packages will be suggested to you to install (related to codec)

The above explanation may not be completely efficient; but, I hope it will work for you, too. I ask any person who can improve my explanations so that others can use it easier and better.

You may also see the same discussion at [[Unable to initialize the video obtain properties (videoreader in Matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486233/unable-to-initialize-the-video-obtain-properties-videoreader-in-matlab](this) page) too.